# After voting to close a question, is it possible to alter the reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I chose the wrong reason for closing a question (I blame my fat fingers), so I decided it was only fair to retract my vote. Now I cannot vote to close the question using the correct reason.

It got me wondering if I had missed something, like an option to change my reason after voting. Does anybody know of any mechanism to do this?

Comment: +1. I've also seen a few things in the Reopen queue where I thought, "this is rightfully closed, but for the wrong reason".