# Can we have the ability to change the reason of cast close vote?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I voted to close this question [Understanding recursive solution to Towers of Hanoi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489062/1065190) as "*Unclear what you're asking*". However, I googled a bit and found a duplicate some time later.

I was wrong, so maybe it is a good idea to let the caster change the reason of his close vote?

Comment: Duplicate of [Ability to change close reason before it gets closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/147400)

Comment: I can sort of see the reasoning behind this, and I've certainly wished I could do this in the past. Actually, I'll admit as a mod, I *have* reopened and then immediately closed a question due to having chosen the wrong reason, just a couple days ago. But the real advice here (especially to myself!) is just to try to be more careful when selecting a close reason.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think this reason is more valid than the [one from earlier today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194925/after-voting-to-close-a-question-is-it-possible-to-alter-the-reason).  Fat fingers happen, so you should be careful before taking actions to make sure you are clicking correctly.  But changes happen after voting - either the post is edited and the reason is no longer valid, or hard to find duplicates pop up.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I had meant to type up something about that, too, but got distracted by my short personal story! hehe...

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is asking to change the close reason after a question is closed.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Where does it say that? Just because the question the OP linked to is closed *now*, several months after the question was asked.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: To me, this question clearly asks to change the close **vote**, not to re-close the question after it was closed for a different close reason.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: The linked question was closed a day after this question was posted here on Meta, so the OP was talking about an active vote.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Last but not least, if it *were* requesting that a closed question could be re-closed for a different dupe, then my irony meter just exploded as this question then should be closed as a dupe of a *different* pre-existing question here on Meta. E.g. *your* post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the linked question says "before it gets closed", this question's mention of time is "some time later", which certainly seems to imply after the question is already closed.  You could say the linked question is a sub-category of this one, but I see them as two distinct questions.  It's definitely not a dupe of mine.  Mine is not focused on changing and individual's close vote, but in allowing more people to vote on the close reason after the question is closed.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: The user found a duplicate some time after voting to close. Nowhere does it state that in the meantime the question got closed. I see no such implication either, and as the question was still open at the time, it is clear to me it was never intended to be read that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm sure you can at least see that this question, since it isn't specific about the timeframe is a broader question.  The broader question should never be closed as a duplicate of the narrower question.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: This is a *underspecified* question, and the closure wasn't disputed by the OP either.