# On Code Review SE, I see curly braces "{}" with reputation

Tags: support, design

On [Code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), the design in the top navigation bar shows curly braces '{}' with user reputation. Here's a snap for reference. Looks like a design flaw.

[image: Code review toolbar]

Comment: Have you tried looking at anybody else's profile to determine what the curly braces represent? This is a very intentional design, not a flaw.

Comment: @Nij intentional and super confusing for people who don't know it represents badges. Using random and/or weird symbols for badges is one of the worst UX decisions I've ever seen, but hey, that's SE they must be special. And looking in profiles won't help, only way to know is either ask around, risking mockery and downvotes, or in case of using PC with a mouse, hover over the weird characters and look at the title that appears.

Comment: Looking at other profiles would almost immediately find different numbers and colours for different users, and discovering they are clearly an intended design element. It is not a huge leap from there to clicking on them and discovering what they represent. They are poor UX only if you presume all your users are lazy and have no curiosity, which is fortunately not the case.

Comment: It's no-repro for MSE, because [it's by-design](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=curly+badge) (and discussed) there on CodeReview.

Comment: Yet again misuse of the worst close reason ever, that is 99% misused because nobody actually understand what it's for. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Rob read the close reason. All of it. There were no changes to the system that rendered the question as obsolete. Totally wrong close reason, and it should not be closed to begin with. You don't like a question? Awesome, downvote it. Don't close or delete it just because you don't agree with it. (By looking for close reasons that don't really apply)

Comment: @Sha, your opinion reflects that of the minority.

Comment: [Should we reopen a question if it is closed with a wrong reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208756/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question

Comment: @Rob no worry I'm fine being in the minority group. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've one bronze badge - [autobiographer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=256316) and that's what you're seeing on the toolbar.

The [badges page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges) shows all the badges with their site icons and they are all curly brackets.

Many other sites have custom badge icons too. Here's some examples...

- on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges) they are mortarboards
- on [The workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges) they are diamonds
- on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges) they are a radio button in the form of a medal